# 'Keyboard' was not declared in this scope - Arduino coding

Tags: arduino, keyboard

I'm writing a simple program for an Arduino that will take the input of 2 buttons and output simulated keys for 2 different functions to use in Clone Hero.

Arduino editor (both online and local versions) spit out

```
'Keyboard' was not declared in this scope
```

The offline editor asks if Keyboard.h is included... Which it obviously is.

Any ideas why?

```cpp
// Keyboard - Version: Latest
#include <Keyboard.h>

//btnWhammy is the button to replace whammy bar function
//btnSP is the button to replace star power activation
//Set Clone Hero to register j for whammy and k for star power

//declaring constant integers for the pins on the Arduino
const int btnWhammy = 2;
const int btnSP = 13;

//Declaring integers for the state of the button press
int btnWhammyState = 0;
int btnSPState = 0;

void setup() {
  //Initialisation of the pins as inputs
  pinMode(btnWhammy, INPUT);
  pinMode(btnSP, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //Setting the button states to the read of the digital pin (LOW is off, HIGH is on)
  btnWhammyState = digitalRead(btnWhammy);
  btnSPState = digitalRead(btnSP);
  //If the whammy button is pressed, send 'j' to the keyboard, wait 100ms then release all keys
  if (btnWhammyState == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.press('j');
    delay(100);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }
  //If the Star Power button is pressed, send 'k' to the keyboard, wait 100ms then release all keys
  if (btnSPState == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.press('k');
    delay(100);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic mistake -- you are probably compiling for a non-Leonardo board, like a Uno. The Keyboard.h library is not included because it is not present for the board you are compiling with.

I took your code and compiled it for Leonardo -- no issues. For Uno, I get the same error as you...

Comment: Ahh right, I haven't purchased my Arduino yet so that's good! So if I buy a leonardo this should compile and run fine and send the J and K keys over the micro USB?

Answer (score 1):

keyboard key was not declared in this scope i found a very simple and working trick of this problem just go to your main file where you declare all other keys that you are facing not declare

```js
#include <DigiKeyboard.h>
#define KEY_UP_ARROW   0x52
#define KEY_DOWN_ARROW   0x51
#define KEY_LEFT_ARROW   0x50
#define KEY_RIGHT_ARROW   0x4F
#define KEY_TAB 0x2B
```